# Robotics: distance in configuration space

Tags: configuration, distance, robotics

In the configuration space, let us say there is a configuration c_1 and a target configuration c_t, is there a way to determine "how far away" c_1 is from c_t? I assume "how far away" can be measures by number of pose changes. Is there a mathematical way of defining this distance between two configurations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The distance between configuration vectors `q_a` and `q_b` in configuration space (C-space) is the norm of the difference between the two vectors (as an aside, configurations are normally denoted `q`). This is true for any n-dimensional space. The equation for this is:

[image: distance norm formula]

To explain a bit more - as I'm sure you know, the distance between point `a` and `b` in 2D Euclidean space is given by the square root of the summation of the `x` and `y` distance squared:

```
d_x = a_x - b_x
d_y = a_y - b_y
distance = sqrt(d_x^2 + d_y^2)
```

To generalise this to n dimensions: the distance between two points `a` and `b` in an n-dimensional space is given by:

[image: distance formula]

Comment: Euclidean distance is not necessarily a meaningful distance metric in all configuration spaces. A simple counter example is SO(2), the configuration space for a rigid body in the plane. A configuration is represented by two distances and an an angle (x, y, theta). In this case, the units don't make sense (you can't add units of angle to units of distance). In that specific case you can use [weighted Euclidean distance](http://planning.cs.uiuc.edu/node188.html) - appropriate distance metrics depend strongly on the topology of the configuration space.

Comment: This is a good point - would it be worth adding it as an additional answer saying it depends on your C-space as to what is the most useful measure?

Comment: I think this isn't relevant for most cases as generally the robots are described in multidimensional space but then the question still stands, how would one go about creating a proper distance function?

Comment: I have a degree in manifold topology and just began studying robotics, but I'll take a shot at this. I think the configuration space $Q^n$ is naturally a submanifold of $SE(3)^N = [\mathbb{R}^3 \rtimes SO(3)]^N$ and so it inherits a Riemannian metric $g$ as a submanifold. One would then use the path-length metric $d(q_1,q_t) = \text{inf}\{l(gamma)\ |\ \gamma: [a,b] \to Q, \gamma(a) = q_1 \text{ and } \gamma(b) = q_t\}$, where $\displaystyle l(\gamma) = \int_a^b \sqrt{g(\frac{d\gamma}{dt},\frac{d\gamma}{dt})}\ dt$ is the length of the path $\gamma$

Comment: (I guess one can't use LaTeX in comments on StackOverflow.)

Comment: So, in principle, $Q$ should be compact, and therefore geodesically complete https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesic_manifold Starting with $q_1$, there should be a minimum distance $D_0$ focal point https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_points (if $Q$ has focal points), and so, for $d(q_1,q_t) < D_0$, there should be a unique geodesic $\gamma_{q_1,q_t}$ from $q_1$ to $q_t$ with $l(\gamma_{q_1,q_t}) = d(q_1,q_t)$ in the path length metric.(Beyond $D_0$, geodesics realizing $d(q_1,q_t)$ need not exist.)